# Can I split up PDFs based on text in specific areas?

Tags: pdf

I work for a University in the admissions office and we get large PDFs of every document that an applicant uploads to us. I need to split these PDFs into separate documents. Each of the separate documents has a head at the top of what type of document it is (Statement of Purpose, Transcript, etc).

I found a program a few weeks ago that at first seemed to work great (A-PDF Splitter). It would look for every type of document in a combined PDF (eg. Statement of Purpose), and if it saw that heading it would create a new PDF named `ORIGINALFILENAME-Statement of Purpose`.

I soon discovered though that the program breaks for no reason on certain PDFs, and I have to take the time to take that PDF out of the queue and start the splitting over again (and we get 250 a day). I contacted their support and they basically told me I was SOL.

If I don't find one soon then I'm going to be spending the entire day splitting PDFs by hand and my boss isn't going to be happy.

Comment: Not really a answer, but since you are at the admissions office, can't you ask the applicants to submit separate pdf files and then merge them at your end, if needed. It is always easier to merge rather than split.